# r data.table dcast - passing list of functions through function call

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

I'm trying to pass a list of functions to the dcast "fun.aggregate" argument - not as a literal but rather a paramater in a function call.

First the direct approach that I'm trying to reproduce within the function call.

```r
library(data.table)

dcast(
    data = as.data.table(mtcars),
    formula = vs ~ am,
    fun.aggregate = list(mean, median),
    value.var = "mpg"
  )
```

```r
   vs mpg_mean_0 mpg_mean_1 mpg_median_0 mpg_median_1
1:  0   15.05000   19.75000         15.2        20.35
2:  1   20.74286   28.37143         21.4        30.40
```

What I've tried is to pass the list of functions to dcast directly, evaluate it via "mget" or "substitute" all without luck.

```r
library(data.table)
test_dcast <- function(a, b) {
  fun_list <- list()
  if (a == 1) {
    fun_list <- c(fun_list, mean)
  }
  if (b == 2) {
    fun_list <- c(fun_list, median)
  }
  dcast(
    data = as.data.table(mtcars),
    formula = vs ~ am,
    fun.aggregate = fun_list,
    value.var = "mpg"
  )
}

test_dcast(1, 2)
```

```r
Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

I'm probably missing something here. Is there a way to make this work somehow?

Comment: hmm i dont get that error with data.table_1.12.2

Comment: oh very interesting. i had data.table 1.12.0 installed. after installing the 1.12.2 patch this actually works. thanks for the hint!

Comment: Looks like this was the fix, fwiw: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3384